# Fetching data to table row and table column

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to fetch data from an api.

So far I have tried to fetch data using an api. I have been using this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data/
It currently console.logs my array but it does not show up in the table rows that i have created.
I think i might have created the rows wrong in my html, but i cant figure how they should have been set up otherwise. Please show a small example or what to google if that is what is wrong.

```
The current error message i get is
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.list is not iterable
    at show (news.js:37:21)
    at getapi (news.js:17:2)
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
// api url
const api_url =
    "https:newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=xxxxxxxxx";

// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
    
    // Storing response
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    // Storing data in form of JSON
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (response) {
        hideloader();
    }
    show(data);
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);

// Function to hide the loader
function hideloader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
function show(data) {
    let tab =
    `<tr>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Url</th>
    </tr>`;
    
    // Loop to access all rows
    for (let r of data.list) {
        tab += `<tr>
            <td>${r.author}</td>
            <td>${r.title}</td>
            <td>${r.description}</td>
            <td>${r.url}</td>
            </tr>`;
    }
    // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
    document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = tab;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="news.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" 
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Here a loader is created which 
             loads till response comes -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" 
                 role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>News</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="news"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Console.log the response of the api. Good change that the list property (the one from the error) does not exists or the result is different

Comment: @n9iels This is what is says when i console log it:
{status: 'ok', totalResults: 10, articles: Array(10)}

Therefore i think it´s not the api that is the issue.

Comment: Your response has the property `articles` and you use `data.list` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing

```
const url = "xxxxxxx"
    fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())              
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)

    let title = document.getElementById("title");
    title.innerText = data.articles[0].title;

    let title1 = document.getElementById("title1");
    title1.innerText = data.articles[1].title;

    let title2 = document.getElementById("title2");
    title2.innerText = data.articles[2].title;

    let title3 = document.getElementById("title3");
    title3.innerText = data.articles[3].title;

    let title4 = document.getElementById("title4");
    title4.innerText = data.articles[4].title;

    let title5 = document.getElementById("title5");
    title5.innerText = data.articles[5].title;
    });
```

And then just a p tag looking like this:

```
<p id="title1"></p>
```

And so on

Comment: I highly recommend you to use some kind of loop for this instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the response correctly.

Working example:

```js
// api url
const api_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments';

// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
    await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            hideloader();
            show(data)
        });
}

// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);

// Function to hide the loader
function hideloader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
function show(data) {
    let tab =
    `<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>`;
    
    // Loop to access all rows
    for (let r of data) {
        tab += `<tr>
            <td>${r.id}</td>
            <td>${r.name}</td>
            <td>${r.body}</td>
            <td>${r.email}</td>
            </tr>`;
    }
    // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
    document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = tab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="news.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" 
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Here a loader is created which 
             loads till response comes -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" 
                 role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>News</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="news"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```